# Decision Tree generating terminal leaves with same classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm relatively new to Decision Trees and I'm stuck with my decision tree algorithm. I'm using cross-validation and parameter tuning to optimize the classification following this example: https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/learning-data-science-day-22-cross-validation-and-parameter-tuning-b14bcbc6b012. But however I tune my parameters I always get results looking like this (here just an example for a small tree):

[Small Decision Tree Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A6so.png)

I don't understand the reasons for this behaviour. Why does the tree generate leaves with the same class (here class2)? Why does it not simply stop after a<=0.375 = TRUE and cut of the leaves with the same class (see picture red rectangle)? Is there a way to prevent this and make the algorithm stop at this point? Or is there a reasonable explanation for this behaviour? Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is my code:

```
     def load_csv(filename):
           dataset = list()
           with open(filename, 'r') as file:
               csv_reader = reader(file)
               for row in csv_reader:
                   if not row:
                       continue
                   dataset.append(row)
           return dataset

    # Convert string column to float
    def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
        for row in dataset:
            row[column] = float(row[column].strip())


    # Load dataset
    filename = 'C:/Test.csv'
    dataset = load_csv(filename)


    # convert string columns to float
    for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
        str_column_to_float(dataset, i)

    # Transform to x and y
    x = []
    xpart = []
    y = []
    for row in dataset:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if i != (len(row) - 1):
                xpart.append(row[i])
            else:
                y.append(row[i])
        x.append(xpart)
        xpart = []

    features_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    labels = ['class1', 'class2']

    #here I tried to tune the parameters 
    #(I changed them several times, this is just an example to show, how the code looks like). 
    # However, I always ended up with terminal leaves with same classes
    """dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=5,
        max_features=8, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease = 0.0, min_impurity_split = None, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='random')"""

    #here, I created the small example
    dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
    dtree.fit(x,y)

    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None) 
    graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
    graph.render("Result") 

    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names= features_names,  
                     class_names=labels,  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)  
    graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
    graph.format = 'png'
    graph.render('Result', view = True)
```

... and a snapshot of my Data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCbOG.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `class` attribute you are referring to is the **majority class** at that particular node, and the colors come from the `filled = True` parameter you pass to [`export_graphviz()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html).

Now, looking at your dataset, you have 147 samples of class1 and 525 samples of class2, which is a fairly imbalanced ratio. It just so happens that the optimal splits for your particular dataset at this depth produce splits where the majority class is class2. This is normal behaviour, and a product of your data, and not altogether surprising given that class2 outnumbers class1 by about 3:1.

As to why the tree doesn't stop when the majority class is the same for the two children of a split, it's because of the way the algorithm works. If left unbounded with no max depth, it will continue until it produces only pure leaf nodes that contain a single class exclusively (and where the [Gini impurity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/339514/205610) is 0). You've set `max_depth = 2` in your example, so the tree simply stops before it can yield all pure nodes.

You'll notice that in the split you've boxed in red in your example, the node on the right is almost 100% class2, with 54 instances of class2 and only 2 of class1. If the algorithm had stopped before that it would produce the node above, with 291-45 class2-class1, which is far less useful.

Perhaps you could increase the max depth of your tree and see if you can separate out the classes further.