# R ranger treeInfo final nodes have the same class

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

When I use ranger for a classification model and `treeInfo()` to extract a tree, I see that sometimes a split results in two identical terminal nodes.
Is this expected behaviour? Why does it make sense to introduce a split where the final nodes are the same?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225204/3048453) question, I take that the `prediction` variable could be the majority class (albeit for python and another random forest implementation). The ranger `?treeInfo` documentation says it should be the predicted class.

### MWE

```r
library(ranger)

data <- iris
data$is_versicolor <- factor(data$Species == "versicolor")
data$Species <- NULL

rf <- ranger(is_versicolor ~ ., data = data,
             num.trees = 1, # no need for many trees in this example
             max.depth = 3, # keep depth at an understandable level
             seed = 1351, replace = FALSE)
treeInfo(rf, 1)
#>   nodeID leftChild rightChild splitvarID splitvarName splitval terminal prediction
#> 1      0         1          2          2 Petal.Length     2.60    FALSE       <NA>
#> 2      1        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE      FALSE
#> 3      2         3          4          3  Petal.Width     1.75    FALSE       <NA>
#> 4      3         5          6          2 Petal.Length     4.95    FALSE       <NA>
#> 5      4         7          8          0 Sepal.Length     5.95    FALSE       <NA>
#> 6      5        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE       TRUE
#> 7      6        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE       TRUE
#> 8      7        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE      FALSE
#> 9      8        NA         NA         NA         <NA>       NA     TRUE      FALSE
```

In this example, the last four rows (final nodes with nodeID 5 and 6, as well as 7 and 8) have the prediction `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
Graphically this would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a (partial) answer to the issue, namely the `mtry` and `min.node.size` arguments and their functionality.

As the random forest chooses only `mtry` variables at each split, the final split might take only variables into account, which do not split the data in a way that results in a maximum gini difference (or whatever metric was chosen) but still in each final node, a given class might prevail.

Playing around with `mtry` and `min.node.size` can change this. But we still might get splits with the same results.

Comment: Hi David,is there a way to visualize the information in treeInfo the way you did here in your initial post? Sorry if this is not an appropriate question. But I am really interested in that.

Comment: @Daniel2805 I cant find the exact code anymore, but I used `data.tree` and `DiagrammeR` to produce the plots!

Comment: thx! That is already helpful. I might try to contact you at a later point in time.